# Can't bind to dtOptions since it isn't a known property of table

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables, ngx-admin

### I'm submitting a problem

### Current behavior

### Expected behavior

try [with-options](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/with-options)

### Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions

```
Can't bind to 'dtOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. ("
  <nb-card-body>
    <!--<table datatable class="row-border hover">-->
    <table datatable [ERROR ->][dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
"): ng:///TablesModule/WithOptionsComponent.html@7:21
Can't bind to 'dtOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. ("
  <nb-card-body>
    <!--<table datatable class="row-border hover">-->
    <table datatable [ERROR ->][dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
"): ng:///TablesModule/WithOptionsComponent.html@7:21
Can't bind to 'dtOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'table'. ("
  <nb-card-body>
    <!--<table datatable class="row-border hover">-->
    <table datatable [ERROR ->][dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
      <thead>
```

### Environment

```
- node version:v10.10.0
- angular version:6.0
- angular-cli version:6.0
- jquery version:3.3.1
- datatables version:1.10.19
- angular-datatables version:7.0.0
```

I fork project [ngx-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) ;
try to integrated angular-datatable

read  [getting started](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started)

But there are exceptions

[project code](https://github.com/HaimmingYu/ngx-admin)

Please help me
[image: 1542804819644]

Comment: Usually this kind of error message is related to missing imports.

Comment: I tried to introduce DataTablesModule to the same result.

Comment: Did you include both the import statement and the DataTablesModule into your module imports array? Are the component on which DataTable is being used on the same module on which you're importing DataTablesModule?

Comment: It seems like a total mess - there is nothing to do with angular here - there is no property as `dtOptions` for an html that is what the error suggest - add some of your code what you tried

Comment: I can't understand where DataTables.Settings came from. I saw angular-datatables demo.https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/tree/master/demo  Neither copy nor paste works.

Comment: what is the version of angular-datatables?

Answer (score 0):

```
set app.module.ts
improt DataTablesModule.forRoot(),
set tables.module.ts
imports DataTablesModule
```

Thank you for your help. The problem has been solved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've given up angular